# Linux terminal command execution with java

Tags: java, linux, terminal, usb-drive

i need help with my program.
what I have to do is that when I click a button my java program will have to execute commands on the linux terminal as shown below, and after that it will have to shut down the program.

```
    String com1 = "rm -r /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/Thermaskin";
    String com2 = "cp -r /media/ctm-tech/FXPoWer_1/Thermaskin /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/";
    String com3 = "java -jar /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/Thermaskin/dist/Thermaskin.jar";
    String com4 = "sudo eject /media/ctm-tech/FXPoWer_1";
    
    try {
        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(com1);
        Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(com2);
        Process p3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(com3);
        Process p4 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(com4);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Qualcosa è andato storto"  + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

    System.exit(0);
```

The problem is that my program only executes the first command, and sometimes it doesn't execute anything.

The commands must update the running program, with a later version present inside the FXPoWer_1 pendrive.

Can someone help me? Thank you very much, waiting for a response

News for "Some Programmers Dude"
This is the code now

```
private void jButton_aggiornaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    runCommand("cp -r /media/ctm-tech/FXPoWer_1/Thermaskin1 /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/");
    runCommand("java -jar /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/Thermaskin1/dist/Thermaskin.jar");
    runCommand("rm -r /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/Thermaskin");
    runCommand("mv /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/Thermaskin1 /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/Thermaskin");
    runCommand("sudo eject /media/ctm-tech/FXPoWer_1");        

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: My guess is that all processes you start will run in *parallel*, meaning the command can happen in any order. If it happens in the wrong order some commands will fail. You need to introduce some synchronization to make sure that the commands are executed one after the other.

Comment: thank you for answer. It might be, how can i do it?

Comment: In its simplest way, [wait for each to finish](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) before starting the next? And if you don't want to ducplicate code, put it all in a separate function.

Comment: yes, i meant, which method i have to call for wait the process?

Comment: And I just linked to it.

Comment: it doesn't work, my program doesn't go on. Freezes on wait

Comment: That seems like a new problem, for a new question. I'll write an answer for the synchronization problem while you start *debugging* your new problem to see when and where the "lockup" seems to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands you try to run will all run in parallel, without any control over which will run first or their order.

That means some command can (and will) fail if the are happening in the wrong order.

One simple way to solve it is to call [`waitFor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) on the `Process` object, to wait for each command to finish before starting the next.

I recommend you create a new function to run a command and wait for it to finish:

```
private void runCommand(String command) {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        // Wait for command to finish
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error running command: "  + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Then you can call this for each of your commands:

```
runCommand("rm -r /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/Thermaskin");
runCommand("cp -r /media/ctm-tech/FXPoWer_1/Thermaskin /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/");
runCommand("java -jar /home/ctm-tech/Documenti/App/Thermaskin/dist/Thermaskin.jar");
runCommand("sudo eject /media/ctm-tech/FXPoWer_1");
```

These commands will now run in the exact sequence called.

Comment: Hi dude, i have one more problem ... i have modify the runCommand order because it wasn't right in that way. I don't know how i can show you, so after this comment i'm going to modify my post for you. So, now the problem is that the CP command does't work, so neither the java -jar works, but the RM yes... why? Sorry about that, im doing work experience in school internships and the company does't know how to help me. They just tell me what to create for them